# Transform referenced XML

Tags: content-management-system, xslt-2.0, pipeline

I have a pipeline question.

I have a workflow where I have a master XML that references multiple XML files. It would be similar to a DITA map, but this is not DITA.

I am having to run an XSLT on the master XML to prepare it for a downstream process for output to the web or other medium.

Part of this transform includes resolving database file paths to relative file paths within the package that is exported from the content management system.

I can perform the transformation on the master XML just fine. However, my question involves running a XSLT on the referenced XML files. They also need the paths corrected.

Here is a simple sample...

```
<master>
<reference url="x-database01.xml"/>
</master>
```

The reference will resolve to something like url="/files/realXMLname.xml". The problem is that I don't know how to then transform realXMLname.XML to resolve the paths there.

```
<content>
<graphic href="x-database02.jpg"/>
</content>
```

The database and the downstream process are 2 different software packages with an out-of-the-box integration. I could write my own pipeline to do the transforms, but it may be cost prohibitive. The current integration only allows for 1 XSLT to be run a the pre-process step.

Is it possible to transform referenced XML files in a single XSLT transform step?

Comment: In principle, this is possible since XSLT 2.0 allows you to create node trees from fragments (loaded from files) and then run templates on these. However, to be able to load them using the `document()` function you will have to determine the exact physical filenames. So. this may just move your problem and not solve it.

Comment: I have a manifest file that tells me the physical filenames of all of the files in the package. Plus I can get the URI of the master XML and construct full filepaths. So, what you are suggesting may be possible. How do I run templates on node trees from separate files?

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The following setup uses a main input XML `input.xml` which only contains a root node and two other XML files `part1.xml` and `part2.xml` which are read using the `document()` function. The XSLT uses `<xsl:apply-templates>` to trigger the conversion of the union of the two XML files. This way it should be possible to combine any number of XML files beforehand into one tree and execute the XSLT process on the resulting tree.

By the way: It turns out that this is already supported in XSLT 1.0 (at least by the `xsltproc` processor).

File `input.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root/>
```

File `part1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root1>
  <element>
    <subelement1 message="Hello from part1.xml"/>
  </element>
</root1>
```

File 'part2.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root2>
  <element>
    <subelement2 message="Hello from part2.xml"/>
  </element>
</root2>
```

With the input above the following XSLT transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="part1" select="document('part1.xml')/root1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="part2" select="document('part2.xml')/root2"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <messages>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$part1|$part2"/>
    </messages>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

  <xsl:template match="subelement1">
    <message>
      <xsl:value-of select="@message"/>
    </message>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="subelement2">
    <message>
      <xsl:value-of select="@message"/>
    </message>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

yields this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messages>
  <message>Hello from part1.xml</message>
  <message>Hello from part2.xml</message>
</messages>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, this isn't what I need. This pulls the content from the linked XML into the master. I need to leave the structure as-is.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand your objection. You said you wanted *run templates on node trees from separate files*. That's exactly what my solution does. If you need several output files (on top) you can use the `<xsl:result-document>` feature.

Comment: Some day I'd like to check out XPROC but I'm not sure if it's available on the msxml facility in our Windows servers, or if XSLT 1.0 is good enough for using it.  In the meantime I wrote a pipeline myself in ASP classic, it was pretty easy for the basics and is only a couple hundred lines of code including bells and whistles.  This was convenient because you can just string an arbitrary  set of transforms specified by a URL argument, e.g. `&transform=This,That,Other` and the ASP cycles through them.  The transforms happen serially in-memory, which is quite fast.  Good luck on your project!